# How to pass kwargs from python to update more than one column in sql

Tags: python, sql, node.js, python-2.7, keyword-argument

So I have my application which is written in nodejs. Currently when I create an issue and then edit that same issue title_name and description, the title name is updated and shown on the front-end, however the description stays the same and does not update. I have been looking through my python code and sql table, but that seem to looks fine, even my index.js file. It will run the update statement for the title and update that, however for description it will not. So far I have the following :

My resources.py :

```
class IssueResource(object):
    def __init__(self, repo):
        self._repo = repo

    def on_get(self, req, resp, issue_id):
        with self._repo.open() as repo:
            issue = repo.issues.fetch_issue(int(issue_id))
            resp.media = _issue_to_json(issue)
            resp.status = falcon.HTTP_200

    def on_put(self, req, resp, issue_id):
        with self._repo.open() as repo:
            update = req.media
            repo.issues.update_issue(issue_id, **update)
            resp.status = falcon.HTTP_204
```

models.py

```
def fetch_issue(self, issue_id):
        cursor = self._conn.cursor()
        try:
            cursor.execute(
                """SELECT
                    id,
                    title,
                    description,
                    opened_datetime,
                    closed_datetime
                    FROM issues
                    WHERE id = {}""".format(issue_id))
            return make_issue(cursor.fetchone())
        finally:
            cursor.close()


def update_issue(self, issue_id, **kwargs):
        cursor = self._conn.cursor()
        try:
            if 'title' in kwargs:
                    cursor.execute(
                        """UPDATE issues SET title = '{}'  WHERE id = {}"""
                            .format(kwargs['title'], issue_id)
                    )
            if 'description' in kwargs:
                cursor.execute(
                    """UPDATE issues SET description = '{}' WHERE id = {}"""
                    .format(kwargs['description'], issue_id)
                )
            if 'closed' in kwargs:
                cursor.execute(
                    """UPDATE issues SET closed_datetime = '{}' WHERE id = {}"""
                    .format(kwargs['closed'].isoformat(), issue_id)
                )
        finally:
            cursor.close()
```

This is the structure of my sql table :

```
CREATE TABLE issues(
  id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  title VARCHAR(255),
  description TEXT,
  opened_datetime CHAR(26) DEFAULT (datetime('now')),
  closed_datetime CHAR(26)
)
```

My front end of my application is as follows : index.js is where all of my routing is set :

```
require('babel-polyfill')
const m = require('mithril')
const {IssuesList, ViewIssue, CreateIssue, EditIssue, ToolbarContainer} = require('./views')
const {IssuesModel} = require('./viewmodels')

const issuesModel = new IssuesModel()

m.route(document.body, '/issues', {
  '/issues': {
    render(vnode) {
      return m(ToolbarContainer, m(IssuesList, {model: issuesModel}))
    }
  },
  '/issues/create': {
    render(vnode) {
      return m(ToolbarContainer, m(CreateIssue, {model: issuesModel}))
    }
  },

  '/issues/:issueId/edit': {
    render(vnode) {
      return m(ToolbarContainer, m(EditIssue, {model: issuesModel, issueId: vnode.attrs.issueId}))
    }
  }
})
```

view.js - This is all of the view of each different page:

```
const m = require('mithril')

class IssuesList {
  constructor(vnode) {
    this.model = vnode.attrs.model
  }
  oninit() {
    this.model.loadIssues()
  }
  view() {
    return m('table.table', [
      m('thead', [
        m('th', 'title'),
        m('th', 'opened'),
        m('th', 'closed')
      ]),
      m('tbody', [
        this.model.list.map(item =>
          m('tr', [
            m('td.title-cell', m("a", {href: `/issues/${item.id}`, oncreate: m.route.link}, item.title)),
            m('td.opened-cell', item.opened),
            m('td.closed-cell', item.closed)
          ])
        )
      ])
    ])
  }
}

class ViewIssue {
  constructor(vnode) {
    this.model = vnode.attrs.model
    this.issueId = vnode.attrs.issueId
  }
  oninit() {
    this.model.loadIssue(this.issueId)
  }
  view() {
    let detail = this.model.issues[this.issueId]
    return detail
    ? m('div',[
        m('.row', [
          m('h1.col-sm-11', detail.title),
          m('.col-sm-1',
            m(
              'a.btn.btn-primary',
              {href: `/issues/${this.issueId}/edit`, oncreate: m.route.link},
              'Edit'
            )
          )
        ]),
        m('dl.row', [
          m('dt.col-sm-3', 'Opened'),
          m('dd.col-sm-3', detail.opened),
          m('dt.col-sm-3', 'Closed'),
          m('dd.col-sm-3', detail.closed),
        ]),
        m('h2', 'Description'),
        m('p.description', detail.description)
      ]
    )
    : m('.alert.alert-info', 'Loading')
  }
}

class EditIssue {
  constructor(vnode) {
    this.model = vnode.attrs.model
    this.issueId = vnode.attrs.issueId
  }
  async oninit() {
    await this.model.loadIssue(this.issueId)
  }
  view() {
    let issue = this.model.issues[this.issueId]
    return issue
    ? m(IssueEditor, {
      title: issue.title,
      descriptionText: issue.description,

      onSubmit: async (fields) => {
        await this.model.updateIssue(this.issueId, fields)
        m.route.set(`/issues/${this.issueId}`)
        m.redraw()
      }
    })
    :m('.alert.alert-info', 'Loading')

  }
}

class CreateIssue {
  constructor(vnode) {
    this.model = vnode.attrs.model
  }
  view() {
    return m(IssueEditor, {
      title: '',
      descriptionText: '',
      onSubmit: async ({descriptionText, title}) => {
        await this.model.createIssue({description: descriptionText, title: title})
        m.route.set(`/issues`)
        m.redraw()
      }
    })
  }
}

class IssueEditor {
  constructor(vnode) {
    this.title = vnode.attrs.title
    this.descriptionText = vnode.attrs.descriptionText
    this.onSubmit = vnode.attrs.onSubmit
  }
  view() {
    return m('form', {onsubmit: e => this.onSubmit({title: this.title, descriptionText: this.descriptionText})}, [
      m('.form-group', [
        m('label', {'for': 'title-input'}, 'Issue Title'),
        m('input.form-control#title-input', {value: this.title, oninput: (e) => {this.title = e.target.value}})
      ]),
      m('.form-group', [
        m('label', {'for': 'description-input'}, 'Description'),
        m('textarea.form-control#description-input', {oninput: (e) => {this.descriptionText = e.target.value}}, this.descriptionText)
      ]),
      m('button.btn.btn-primary#save-button', {type: 'submit'}, 'Save')

    ])
  }
}


module.exports = {IssuesList, ViewIssue, EditIssue, CreateIssue, IssueEditor}
```

Main script to run the python app :

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import argparse
import falcon
import os

from .resources import IssueResource, IssuesResource
from .models import Repository


def _index_middleware(app):
    def handler(environ, start_response):
        if environ['PATH_INFO'] == '/':
            environ['PATH_INFO'] = '/index.html'
        return app(environ, start_response)
    return handler


def make_api(database_location, migrate_database=True):
    api = falcon.API()
    repo = Repository(database_location)
    if migrate_database:
        repo.migrate_database()
    api.add_route('/issues', IssuesResource(repo))
    api.add_route('/issues/{issue_id}', IssueResource(repo))
    static_dir = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(__file__, '..', '..', 'dist'))
    api.add_static_route('/', static_dir)
    return _index_middleware(api)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    from werkzeug.serving import make_server

    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Run a bug tracker server")
    parser.add_argument('--interface', default='0.0.0.0',
                        help="Interface to bind to")
    parser.add_argument('--port', default=8640,
                        help="Port to listen on")
    parser.add_argument('--database-location',
                        default=os.path.join(
                            os.path.dirname(__file__), '..', 'database.db'
                        ), help="Where to store the database")
    parser.add_argument('--no-database-migrations', action='store_true',
                        help="Do not perform database migrations")
    parser.add_argument('--clean', action='store_true',
                        help="Delete the database and start from clean")
    args = parser.parse_args()
    if args.clean:
        os.remove(args.database_location)

    api = make_api(args.database_location, not args.no_database_migrations)
    httpd = make_server(args.interface, args.port, api)
    print "Serving on {args.interface}:{args.port}".format(args=args)
    httpd.serve_forever()
```

Comment: So what is running this Python code? Are you using some kind of framework? How is data getting from Node to Python?

Comment: Also note, you must **never ever ever** form SQL queries by string substitution, as that leaves you wide open to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: @DanielRoseman

I have just updated my question with the front-end framework being used to explain the data getting from Node to Python . I have posted what is relevant

Comment: I can't see anything here that explains how that Python code is being called or how it is run in the first place.

Comment: Please see the question again , i have added the main script for this @DanielRoseman

Comment: What is happening is , it fails on the section where it is trying to UPDATE the description. I have added in print statements and that is where the issue occurs

Comment: @airlogic Before ANYTHING else, **fix your code to use prepared statements instead of string formatting** for the SQL queries. This is a major security issue, but it's also a cause of bugs wrt/ proper quoting and escaping. This might even (or not) be the source of your problem here.

Comment: Good point made. Did not recognise that. Could you point or provide an example of how it should be done instead @brunodesthuilliers

Comment: http://bobby-tables.com/ and more specifically http://bobby-tables.com/python